# How to display values near bar chart in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I'm creating a bar chart using visualforce charting and I'd like to add the row values near the bars on chart. Currently it looks like this:
[image]

And that's what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

Is it even possible ? I've went through the whole charting section in VF developer's guide and couldn't find that option.

I have 2 values for xField in barSeries, so using chartLabel won't work.

```
<apex:barSeries title="TitleA,TitleB" stacked="false" orientation="horizontal" axis="left"
xField="Actual,Planned" yField="allocationName" colorSet="red,blue" highlight="false">
```

Thanks!
Kamil

Comment: I think its possible. Here is a possible duplicate - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098gZIAQ

Comment: @SantanuHalder Thanks for the suggestion but it won't work if there are 2 values for xField in barSeries like in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result with the combination of apex:chartLabel and apex:barSeries like below.

```
<apex:barSeries title="Areas" orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="name" yField="data1" tips="true">
    <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
    <apex:chartLabel field="data1" display="outside" orientation="horizontal"/>
</apex:barSeries>
```

The orientation attribute in apex:chartLabel determines the placement of the label within the bar chart.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it won't work in my case. Please take a look at edited question.